# Generating the CSharp refit Clients from the Repo

Tags: java, c#, swagger, refit

I am trying to generate the Refit Api Clients from the Git Project : `https://github.com/itofinity/swagger-csharp-refit` I have installed Maven and created Project. But The only issue that I am facing is that.

```
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.ignore.CodegenIgnoreProcessor - No .swagger-codegen-ignore file found.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:731)
        at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:285)
        at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
```

For some reason I have to create only refit client and this is giving error.

using Command :`java -cp target/CSharpRefitCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.2.jar;tools/swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -l csharprefit  -i C:\json\isfs.json -o clients/ITST`

I have corrected Jar path issue and all so that is fine. Can anyone Help with this please. it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I Do not know how it resolved but it did. This followed change.

in your json file

change

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
```

to this

```
{
  "swagger": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
```

and it resolved.